# How can I ensure that all organizations have signed the chaincode to install?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

In Hyperledger Fabric 1.3, 
how can I ensure that all organizations have signed the chaincode to install ?

I could sign the code, but it seems that no component verifies the signature.

Details are as below:

### Preconditions

- Fabric 1.3
- I have two orgs, org1 and org2.
- org1 wants to verify that org2 has signed the code, and vice versa, for non-repudiation (undeniability).
- I know that we can install chaincode without signatures by `peer chaincode install`.

### Expected Behaviour

In the below Commands, I expected that:

- Option A must succeed, because the chaincode includes signatures from both orgs.
- Option B must produce some kind of error or warning, because the chaincode lacks a signature from org2.

### Actual Behaviour

- Not only Option A but B also succeeds with no errors, which is against the expectation.

### Commands

```
org1> peer chaincode package -n mycc -v 0 example02/cmd -s -S \
          -i "AND('Org1MSP.admin')" cc.out


Option A:
   org2> peer chaincode signpackage cc.out signedcc.out
   org1> peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 0 signedcc.out
   org2> peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 0 signedcc.out

Option B:
   org1> peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 0 cc.out
   org2> peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 0 cc.out


org1> peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer:7050 -C mychannel \
          -n mycc -v 0 -c '(snip)' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"


# Then Org2 makes a query.
```

### The flow

[image: The flow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no enforcement of signed chaincode packages within Hyperledger Fabric.  In version 2.0 (targeted for late March), there will be a new lifecycle for chaincode which will provide this type of functionality.

For the current 1.3 and upcoming 1.4 releases, it will be up to the organization installing the chaincode to check that they have the right / enough signatures for the chaincode package prior to installing.

Comment: In the case the org wish to check the signatures, how will they achieve that ? I couldn't find something like ` peer chaincode verify`.

Comment: Unfortunately, we never implemented that so you would need to write the code to do that yourself.   If you look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/core/common/ccpackage/ccpackage.go#L215 it shows how the signature is created and https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/core/common/ccpackage/ccpackage.go#L127 shows how the signed install package (with detached signatures) is created.